# How to print particular "div" area in asp.net core component.razor ..?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-blazor, razor-components

Here I place a coding of my basic application in asp.net core, this is for print div which is mention by `id="printableArea"` . this code work clearly.

```
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div!" />
<div id="printableArea" class="stylesheet">
    <table  id="myTable" class="table">
         <thead>

            <tr>                 
                <th>Pipe Type</th>
                <th>DIA</th>
                <th>Laek Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

script

```
<script>
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

but the problem is, the same thing i have to do in component.razor, I didn't got any idea, how to excute this without script. other hand blazor page( component.razor) not allowd to write script. please give your solutions.

```
<input type="button" />
<div id="printableArea" >
<div>
```

```
@code{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way:

In _Host.cshtml put this code in script section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function printDiv() {
            var divContents = document.getElementById("PrintDiv").innerHTML;
            var a = window.open('', '', 'height=500, width=500');
            a.document.write('<html>');
            a.document.write('<body > <br>');
            a.document.write(divContents);
            a.document.write('</body></html>');
            a.document.close();
            a.print();
        }
    </script>
```

In razor component:

```
<div id="PrintDiv" class="row">
    <h1>Megatron</h1>
    <h3>Hola Mundo Megatron</h3>
    Here I put my design, for example an invoice.
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="PrintAsiento">Imprimir DIV</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In code section:

```
public async Task PrintAsiento()
    {
        await IJS.InvokeVoidAsync("printDiv");
    }
```